# Format Django rendered date string dates into YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: python, django, date, format

When we pass `date` object in django view and render in html, it outputs in below format.

`'Oct. 7, 2022', 'Sept. 9, 2022', 'Aug. 12, 2022', 'July 15, 2022', 'June 17, 2022', 'May 20, 2022', 'April 22, 2022', 'March 25, 2022', 'Feb. 25, 2022', 'Jan. 28, 2022', 'Dec. 31, 2021', 'Feb. 11, 2022', 'Nov. 5, 2021'`

This is example of how each month looks like. I want to convert it into `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I am using below approach which is working version but I am looking for **optimized** code for the same.

```
import re
import datetime

date_value = 'Sept. 9, 2022'

date_value = re.split("[., ]", date_value)
date_value[0] = date_value[0][:3]
date_value = ' '.join(date_value)
date_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_value, '%b %d %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(date_value)

>> 2022-09-09
```

Is there any other way to directly convert it into this format?

This question is not about formatting django date like `date_value |date:"Y-M-d"` on UI. Rather I am looking to do in python backend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your settings.py file looks like, but try to set the settings parameters to

```
#settings.py
...
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

I have a project with these settings and it displays the dates in the HTML template, without further formatting (see image).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZiRe.png)

If you want to do this just for some date values inside a view, you could call the 'isoformat()' function from the [datetime python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#). Look how you could use it for a DateField in the code below.

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def get_article_date(request):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=1)
    formatted_date = article.delivery_date.isoformat()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'date': formatted_date})
```

And if you are using a QuerySets and not only rendering dates, you could write a custom template filter, which formats the dates in the template (see code below).

**views.py**

```
def get_article_date(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'articles': articles})
```

**template.html**

```
{% load custom_filters %}
{% for article in articles %}
    <p>{{ article.name }}, delivered on {{ article.delivery_date|format_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**custom_filters.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def format_date(value):
    return value.isoformat()
```

Comment: I cannot change settings.py for this particular usecase. It can break several things.

Comment: @Rajnishkumar I edited my solution. You can use the isoformat() function on a date field of a model to transform it to your desired format. It worked with my example.